# How can I create a Filtered Index with fluent NHibernate?

Tags: sql-server-2008, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a column which I need to allow nulls, but I want a unique constraint to prevent duplicate values when the value is not null.

I've done this by using a filtered index as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EventBooking_AssociatedSlot_IUC
ON [Core].[EventBooking] (AssociatedSlot)
WHERE AssociatedSlot IS NOT NULL
```

Is it possible to create this index with Fluent NHibernate?

thanks in advance.

Comment: none i know of until FNH implements arbitrary sql objects like in hbm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not currently possible